# SSRS Report logic When Retrieving Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a report which among other filters there is on called “include blank names”
If yes is selected then include the rows where the names column is null. There’s no empty string

If no then is doesn’t include blank.

Parameter
@blank — 1 blank included
            —  2 blank isn’t included

Question is
Is the best approach to do this check by checking this parameter on a if statement Or is there a way to include in the select query itself and don’t have the if?

If @blank = 1
Select * from table
Else
Select * from table Where (names is not null)

Comment: Thanks but I don’t think that would work for my case. I edited the question. There’s no blanks but either null or a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this-

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ( (@Blank = 1) OR (@Blank = 2 AND (Names<>'' OR Names IS NULL)) )
```

Comment: That I believe might work. I’ll give it a try tomorrow morning

Comment: @Camus, Unit tested the above script! Glad to know If this works well for you!

Comment: It did. Thanks. Simple solution